# Threads vs. Async

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, twisted

I have been reading up on the threaded model of programming versus the asynchronous model from this really good article. http://krondo.com/blog/?p=1209

However, the article mentions the following points.

1. An async program will simply outperform a sync program by switching between tasks whenever there is a I/O.
2. Threads are managed by the operating system.

I remember reading that threads are managed by the operating system by moving around TCBs between the Ready-Queue and the Waiting-Queue(amongst other queues). In this case, threads don't waste time on waiting either do they?

In light of the above mentioned, what are the advantages of async programs over threaded programs?

Comment: No, I meant Threaded vs. Async. I mentioned point one only because it was something I understood from the article.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

1. It is very difficult to write code that is thread safe. With asyncronous code, you know exactly where the code will shift from one task to the next and race conditions are therefore much harder to come by.
2. Threads consume a fair amount of data since each thread needs to have its own stack. With async code, all the code shares the same stack and the stack is kept small due to continuously unwinding the stack between tasks.
3. Threads are OS structures and are therefore more memory for the platform to support. There is no such problem with asynchronous tasks.

#### Update 2022:

Many languages now support stackless co-routines (async/await). This allows us to write a task almost synchronously while yielding to other tasks (`await`ing) at set places (sleeping or waiting for networking or other threads)

Comment: To elaborate a bit: 
1. The I/O part of threaded code is relatively easy but managing the shared state between threads (using locks/queues/etc) without race conditions is what makes it tricky.  Using an async model means you have less going on at the same time so races are easily avoided.
2/3. each thread will consume at least one memory page of stack (4KB or 8KB typically), plus some unknown amount of memory for other data structures related to that thread's state.

Comment: One more item to add: it's easier to get, share, and reason about the result of delayed tasks, just `res = await task`. While one needs to use some shared object like a queue to get results from the code executed in a separate thread.

Comment: Then is there any value in learning thread model today?

Answer (score 16):

There are two ways to create threads:

**synchronous threading** - the parent creates one (or more) child threads and then must wait for each child to terminate. Synchronous threading is often referred to as the [fork-join model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork%E2%80%93join_model).

**asynchronous threading** - the parent and child run concurrently/independently of one another. Multithreaded servers typically follow this model.

*resource - [http://www.amazon.com/Operating-System-Concepts-Abraham-Silberschatz/dp/0470128720](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470128720)*

Answer (score 15):

1. Assume you have 2 tasks, which does not involve any IO (on multiprocessor machine).
   In this case threads outperform Async. Because Async like a 
   single threaded program executes your tasks in order. But threads can 
   execute both the tasks simultaneously.
2. Assume you have 2 tasks, which involve IO (on multiprocessor machine).
   In this case both Async and Threads performs more or less same (performance 
   might vary based on number of cores, scheduling, how much process intensive 
   the task etc.). Also Async takes less amount of resources, low overhead and
   less complex to program over multi threaded program.

How it works?
   Thread 1 executes Task 1, since it is waiting for IO, it is moved to IO 
   waiting Queue. Similarly Thread 2 executes Task 2, since it is also involves 
   IO, it is moved to IO waiting Queue. As soon as it's IO request is resolved 
   it is moved to ready queue so the scheduler can schedule the thread for 
   execution.

Async executes Task 1 and without waiting for it's IO to complete it 
   continues with Task 2 then it waits for IO of both the task to complete. It 
   completes  the tasks in the order of IO completion.

Async best suited for tasks which involve Web service calls, Database query 
   calls etc.,
   Threads for process intensive tasks.

The below video explains about`Async vs Threaded model` and also when to use etc., 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kdzL3r-yJZY

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. **Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.** Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: @Lakshmipathi can you please elaborate more on your (1. example). I think that yourproposed multi-threading implementation also takes advantage of multi-processing. The thing is that you could also have multiple threads on a single core and in my humble opinion your first example is somewhat misleading.

Comment: The original question has a 'python' tag and 1. in the answer is not applicable due to GIL.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, note that a lot of the detail of how threads are implemented and scheduled are very OS-specific. In general, you shouldn't need to worry about threads waiting on each other, since the OS and the hardware will attempt to arrange for them to run efficiently, whether asynchronously on a single-processor system or in parallel on multi-processors.

Once a thread has finished waiting for something, say I/O, it can be thought of as runnable. Threads that are runnable will be scheduled for execution at some point soon. Whether this is implemented as a simple queue or something more sophisticated is, again, OS- and hardware-specific. You can think of the set of blocked threads as a set rather than as a strictly ordered queue.

Note that on a single-processor system, asynchronous programs as defined here are equivalent to threaded programs.

Answer (score 1):

see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)#I.2FO_and_scheduling

However, the use of blocking system calls in user threads (as opposed to kernel threads) or fibers can be problematic. If a user thread or a fiber performs a system call that blocks, the other user threads and fibers in the process are unable to run until the system call returns. A typical example of this problem is when performing I/O: most programs are written to perform I/O synchronously. When an I/O operation is initiated, a system call is made, and does not return until the I/O operation has been completed. In the intervening period, the entire process is "blocked" by the kernel and cannot run, which starves other user threads and fibers in the same process from executing.

According to this, your whole process might be blocked, and no thread will be scheduled when one thread is blocked in IO. I think this  is os-specific, and will not always be hold.

Answer (score 1):

To be fair, let's point out the benefit of Threads under CPython GIL compared to async approach:

1. it's easier first to write typical code that has one flow of events (no parallel execution) and then to run multiple copies of it in separate threads: it will keep each copy responsive, while the benefit of executing all I/O operations in parallel will be achieved automatically;
2. many time-proven libraries are sync and therefore easy to be included in the threaded version, and not in async one;
3. some sync libraries actually let GIL go at C level that allows parallel execution for tasks beyond I/O-bound ones: e.g. NumPy;
4. it's harder to write async code in general: the inclusion of a heavy CPU-bound section will make concurrent tasks not responsive, or one may forget to await the result and finish execution earlier.

So if there are no immediate plans to scale your services beyond ~100 concurrent connections it may be easier to start with a threaded version and then rewrite it... using some other more performant language like Go.

Answer (score 0):

Async I/O means there is already a thread in the driver that does the job, so you are duplicating functionality and incurring some overhead. On the other hand, often it is not documented how exactly the driver thread behaves, and in complex scenarios, when you want to control timeout/cancellation/start/stop behaviour, synchronization with other threads, it makes sense to implement your own thread. It is also sometimes easier to reason in sync terms.

Comment: That's not how async I/O works at all.  Fundamentally, I/O is event-driven (you initiate an I/O to a device, later, the device completes it and hopefully tells you so with an interrupt).  There are some kinds of I/O (like disk I/O) where the driver uses a kernel thread for somewhat obscure reason; but for networks, it's async operations all the way down.