# Related to Event dispatch thread

Tags: java

I have heard by a stackoverflow member that invoke later method schedules an asynchronous event on the EDT.

1. What is meant by asynchronous event?
2. When does the processing of run method in invokelater() takes place.

Answer (score 0):

Asynchronous is [running processes in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024056/threads-vs-async).

`invokeLater()` places the [process in a queue to be executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196889/swingutilities-invokelater).

These are two separate questions previously answered on StackOverflow.